# HTML page not rendering properly on Apache on Raspberry Pi

Tags: jquery, html, css, apache, raspberry-pi

I purchased a template from monstertemplates.com - and put it on my Raspberry Pi that is running the LAMP stack.  I also have jQuery installed.  When I pull up the page it is only text - no CSS and no graphics.

These are the modules that are currently loaded:

```
libjs-jquery is already the newest version.
libjs-jquery set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common lesstif2 liblcms1 libopenjpeg2 libpoppler19
  libxp6
```

And this is the information on the template...

1170 Grid System, CSS 3, HTML 5, JQuery, LESS, Semantic Code, Valid Coding

What am I missing?

UPDATE ---  It was a simple rights issue - no rights setup on the sub-directories that contain javascript, images, and css

Answer (score 0):

Need some more information on what kind of errors you can see in your browser console, but my first guess is that there's something wrong with the location of the sites assets (images and css files etc).

Have you renamed any files or folders? Make sure everything is named correctly.

If that isn't the case, can you open the console on any browser and edit your comment with any error messages?